# Function to read from file and write to new one

Tags: python

I need to define a function that reads csv files, and after that i need to do some functions that takes the information from thees chosen files and does some calculations, that later is written to a new file.
This is how part of the code looks:

```
if str1 == 'small':
    with open('small.csv', 'r+') as small:
        read_small = csv.reader(small)
        for row in read_small:
            print row
elif str1 == 'big':
    with open('big.csv', 'r+') as big:
            read_big = csv.reader(big)
            for row in read_big:
                print row    
else:
    print "File not found"
```

Now, it prints out the files as i want them to look, but when i try to def a function that does not print out the file, just returns it for me so i can call it in other functions for calculations it does not work! 
Any tips?
(I have googled as **** to find a solution, and i am a newbie)

Comment: Rather than printing the rows you probably want to collect them in a list and return that list?

Answer (score -1):

> but when i try to def a function that does not print out the file, just returns it for me

```
def get_lines(my_str):
   file_picker = {'small': 'small.csv', 'big':'big.csv'}
   with open(file_picker[my_str]) as f:
      my_csv_reader = csv.reader(f)
      return [ row for row in my_csv_reader ]
```

Comment: Yea, but i want it to be returned in the way as it is printed out above.
The user can choose 2 files, and then the function should open, the chosen file and return it in the way my for-loops does right now

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you want to get back a list of all the rows.

```
def get_rows():
    rows_to_return = []
    with open('file.csv', 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
            rows_to_return.append(row)
    return rows_to_return
```